# PHP Inline IF statement convention

Tags: php

first of all, I am quite new to PHP and web development in general.
I see people using the Ternary Operators quite a lot but sometimes I like the following solution.
If there is only need for if statements, is the following code against any general php convention ?

```
if($result->num_rows < 1) return $response->error(400, "Target with ID " . $target->id . " does not exist");
```

Best regards,
Fabian

Comment: That's a very opinionated question. About conventions you might check https://www.php-fig.org/ (PHP Standard Recommendation)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although the [PSR-12](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-12/) doesn't allow the use of `if` statements without braces, it's a widely used practice in the community, especially to do quick early returns.

Comment: Quick early returns is exactly what I need. 
Wrapping braces around it in the same line sounds quite silly so I guess I´ll go with the community and use it. Thank you